# Uploading csv file to Big Query Timestamp Parse error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am building a node.js script to upload csv files to big query but I am running into a parse error:

1. Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'XXXX-X-XX XX:XX:XX' as TIMESTAMP for field date_time_received_utc (position 70) starting at location 1279  with message 'Could not parse 'XXXX-X-XX XX:XX:XX' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]] or YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]'

I believe that I have it in the correct format but I am not sure what the issue is. Has anyone run into this issue?

So far I have tried removing the seconds from the timestamp but I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue using Python, in which it was necessary to append to the timestamp information the timezone. So inserting the timezone solved my problem.

You can check [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#.datetime) for the data formats in node.js to BigQuery api. As I could read, there could be something with the data type, maybe it should be datetime.